# how to update previously loaded data after user update his profile

Tags: ios, iphone

I have one logical question.

I have one iOS app. which uses php mysql as backend. I am getting other user's feeds/Posts on the app home page. I am first getting latest post and saves it locally then display User Post and his details from local.

Now if some user has created one feed, that I will get and display at app side. after sometime if user changes his profile details(like changes his picture). So until that Post/feed updated I could not get know that the user has changed his picture. and every time user's old picture and details will be shown.

So can anyone suggest me which was the better way to update user's information? same like facebook does

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Logical Answer: 
Make an api in the backend which will return only the updated post.
From app side add a timer for around 3sec/5sec and call the api again and again, and refresh the feed with the current changes. If there is no changes you don't have to refresh the feed. 
Make sure from the api you will return only changes not the whole feed again and again it will consume more data if you do so.

Comment: what if user does not update his feed and updates his profile. in that case app will not get any feed and will still display wrong profile picture.

Comment: You have to apply same concept.